# Async function is not recognized in NodeJS when required from another JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files: `getPopular.js` and `getPlayListByBPM.js`. I am importing function from `getPopular.js` to `getPlayListByBPM.js`.

In `getPopular.js`, I wrote two async functions:

```
var getPopularArtists = async () => {
    //https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        return getArtistNameIdMap(body, {});
    })
}

var getPopularTracks = async () => {
    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        return getTrackIdList(body, {});
    })
}

module.exports = {
    GetPopularArtists: getPopularArtists,
    GetPopularTracks: getPopularTracks,
}
```

with `getArtistNameIdMap` and `getTrackIdList` non-async functions.

In `getPlayListByBPM.js`, I import the functions like this:

```
const GetPopular = require('./getPopular');

var popularArtists = await GetPopular.GetPopularArtists();

var getPlaylistsByBPM = (req, res) => {
console.log(popularArtists);
res.send("This is my BPM" + req.params.BPM);
}
```

While it gives me:

```
var popularArtists = await GetPopular.GetPopularArtists();
                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I would like to know how can should I call `getPopularArtists` function when having them imported into another JS file?

Comment: It has nothing to do with it being in another source file. The error message explains **exactly** what the problem is: you can only use `await` (for now) in an `async` function. Your code does not follow that rule.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is trying to convey that `await` needs to be used inside an `async`-declared function.

The below is what is expected, I believe:

```
var getPlaylistsByBPM = async (req, res) => {
  var popularArtists = await GetPopular.GetPopularArtists();
  console.log(popularArtists);
  res.send("This is my BPM" + req.params.BPM);
}
```